# Logcat issues on android

Tags: android, mobile, logging

I am using the app AIDE to develop directly on my devices, without using eclipse or an external machine.

I am getting conflicting logcat outputs on my two devices, one a Galaxy Nexus, the other a Nexus 7. Both are on Jellybean, both are running the same version of the IDE app and both are using the same source code I'm writing.

On my phone I see all the log commands from my app, and on the tablet, none of them.

I have also tried building test hello world apps that come with the IDE app, then adding logging to it. Again, the phone works, the tablet doesn't.

I have a;so checked the settings on the devices under developer, and both have the same including USB debugging on.

Finally, in the app itself, I have tried both having android:debuggable="true" in the manifest, and not having it. It always works on themphone, never on the tablet.

UPDATE

After doing a search on jellybean logs not just android ones, it would appear that android/google has turned off seeing logs on 3rd party apps. You can now only see system logs or logs from the app that you're using I.e. you can't use one app to see another apps logs.

I'm still a bit confused as both my devices are on jellybean, as I mentioned, and one can see all logs, the other can't. However....the kernel's are different.  The tablet is 3.1, the phone 3.0.31.

I believe the log change must have come between these versions.

So now I'm left thinking I'm going to have to root to be able to see logs, or only debug when I have my laptop to hand which isn't often.

Now if anyone knows how to root either a galaxy nexus or nexus 7 without wiping the data......

Comment: How are you accessing LogCat?

Comment: In eclipse try opening up the devices screen and try double clicking on the device. I've had this issue a couple of times and this is what i do to solve it.

Comment: @Avinash, I'm not using eclipse. I'm developing directly on the device.

Comment: @CommonsWare, there is an option inside the app which brings up the logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jelly Bean no longer allows newly-installed apps to view arbitrary messages in LogCat. More specifically, newly-installed apps can no longer hold the `READ_LOGS` permission. If you had installed AIDE on the phone prior to it getting the upgrade to Jelly Bean, that would explain the symptoms that you are seeing.

However, you do not need to root a phone to view logging data. Logging to LogCat is a convenience mechanism. You are welcome to log someplace else (e.g., external storage), using standard Java logging stuff (e.g., `java.util.logging`), so that you can view your logs.

Comment: Ah, so android.util.log goes to logcat, but i can setup my own logging to the sdcard using the java logging class? Great, thanks.

Comment: @RussWheeler: I haven't used `java.util.logging` in ages, but it should support logging to files. You could probably find a `log4j` recipe somewhere as well.

Comment: Ah, so android.util.log goes to logcat, but i can setup my own logging to the sdcard using the java logging class? Great, thanks.

Oh and thanks for clarifying why the logs work on my phone and not tablet. Shame I can't put ICS on the tablet, reinstall AIDE, then upgrade back to Jelllybean!

Comment: Oops, got distracted and timed out on editting.

Log4j recipe? What's a 'recipe'???

Comment: @RussWheeler: By "recipe" I meant "a set of instructions and classes designed for using `log4j` in an Android environment". I seem to recall seeing that somebody cooked up `log4j` support for sending output to LogCat, which suggests that somebody has `log4j` working for Android. I only mentioned it as an example of the possibility of using third-party logging libraries, if `java.util.logging` is unsuitable for whatever reason.

Comment: You can use [logback-android](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android) for that.

Comment: Cheers Commonware. I decided to make, my own very simple logging class just to send myself messages and variable values etc.

user46874 - will check that out if I ever need anything more serious

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, none of the answers above work. That's what happened to me when i was using a Nexus 7 along with Eclipse on a laptop, to debug an app. This happened especially when i started debugging a different app from the one that was debugged earlier. i did two things to finally have logcat messages appear on eclipse's logcat window.

First, there is a setting called 'Select Debug app' under 'Developer Options' on the Nexus 7 tablet. i had to select the particular app being debugged (from the list of apps that it shows - that were debugged some time before).

Second, i had to kill adb server and restart the server.  After these two steps, the logcat messages started appearing from the new app being debugged.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the android.utils.Log like this for extensibility:

```
public class Log {
    // Constants
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static final String TAG = Log.class.getName();

    public static final int VERBOSE = android.util.Log.VERBOSE;
    public static final int DEBUG = android.util.Log.DEBUG;
    public static final int INFO = android.util.Log.INFO;
    public static final int WARN = android.util.Log.WARN;
    public static final int ERROR = android.util.Log.ERROR;
    public static final int ASSERT = android.util.Log.ASSERT;

    // Extension interface
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public interface LogExtension {
        void onLog(int priority, String tag, String msg, Throwable tr);
    }

    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, LogExtension> logExtensions = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, LogExtension>();

    public static void addExtension(String tag, LogExtension extension) {
        if (tag != null && extension != null) {
            Log.logExtensions.put(tag, extension);
        }
    }

    public static void removeExtension(String tag) {
        Log.logExtensions.remove(tag);
    }


    // android.util.Log wrapper
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static int d(String tag, String msg) {
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(DEBUG, tag, msg, null);
        }
        return android.util.Log.d(tag, msg);
    }

    public static int d(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr){
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(DEBUG, tag, msg, tr);
        }
        return android.util.Log.d(tag, msg, tr);
    }

    public static int e(String tag, String msg){
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(ERROR, tag, msg, null);
        }
        return android.util.Log.e(tag, msg);
    }

    public static int e(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(ERROR, tag, msg, tr);
        }
        return android.util.Log.e(tag, msg, tr);
    }

    public static String getStackTraceString(Throwable tr) {
        return android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(tr);
    }

    public static int i(String tag, String msg) {
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(INFO, tag, msg, null);
        }
        return android.util.Log.i(tag, msg);
    }

    public static int i(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(INFO, tag, msg, tr);
        }
        return android.util.Log.i(tag, msg, tr);
    }

    public static boolean isLoggable(String tag, int level) {
        return android.util.Log.isLoggable(tag, level);
    }

    public static int println(int priority, String tag, String msg) {
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(priority, tag, msg, null);
        }
        return android.util.Log.println(priority, tag, msg);
    }

    public static int v(String tag, String msg) {
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(VERBOSE, tag, msg, null);
        }
        return android.util.Log.v(tag, msg);
    }

    public static int v(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(VERBOSE, tag, msg, tr);
        }
        return android.util.Log.v(tag, msg, tr);
    }

    public static int w(String tag, Throwable tr) {
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(WARN, tag, null, tr);
        }
        return android.util.Log.w(tag, tr);
    }

    public static int w(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(WARN, tag, msg, tr);
        }
        return android.util.Log.w(tag, msg, tr);
    }

    public static int w(String tag, String msg) {
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(WARN, tag, msg, null);
        }
        return android.util.Log.w(tag, msg);
    }

    public static int wtf(String tag, Throwable tr) {
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(ASSERT, tag, null, tr);
        }
        return android.util.Log.wtf(tag, tr);
    }

    public static int wtf(String tag, String msg) {
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(ASSERT, tag, msg, null);
        }
        return android.util.Log.wtf(tag, msg);
    }

    public static int wtf(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        for (LogExtension extension : Log.logExtensions.values()) {
            extension.onLog(ASSERT, tag, msg, tr);
        }
        return android.util.Log.wtf(tag, msg, tr);
    }

    // Convenience
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static String acronymForPriority(int priority) {
        switch (priority) {
            case VERBOSE: {
                return "V";
            }
            case DEBUG: {
                return "D";
            }
            case INFO: {
                return "I";
            }
            case WARN: {
                return "W";
            }
            case ERROR: {
                return "E";
            }
            case ASSERT: {
                return "WTF";
            }
            default: {
                return "?";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then find/replace android.util.Log with the fully qualified name of this Wrapper. You can simply extend the Logger by implementing the `LogExtension` interface:

```
public class LogCatBuffer implements Log.LogExtension{
    // Attributes
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private int linesOfLog;
    private Queue<String> logCatContents;
    private DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    // Construction
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private LogCatBuffer(int linesOfLog) {
        this.linesOfLog = linesOfLog;
        this.logCatContents = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
    }

    // LogExtension implementation
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void onLog(int priority, String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        Date now = new Date();
        String loggingMessage = this.dateFormatter.format(now) +
                " " +
                android.os.Process.myPid() +
                " " +
                Log.acronymForPriority(priority) +
                "/" +
                tag +
                ": " +
                (msg != null ? msg : "") +
                (msg != null && tr != null ? "\n" : "") +
                (tr != null ? Log.getStackTraceString(tr) : "");
        this.logCatContents.add(loggingMessage);
        if (this.logCatContents.size() > this.linesOfLog) {
            this.logCatContents.poll();
        }
    }

    // Export
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(256 * this.linesOfLog);
        for (String line : this.logCatContents) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

You can then dump the `LogCatBuffer.toString()` output into a text file, that looks very much like what you are used to from the LogCat console.

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu->more->project ->
Build variants -> select debug-aide